# Circleci + cypress: how to change config.yml without committing to github?

Tags: cypress, circleci

I'm looking for a way to conveniently run only a specific set of Cypress spec files on Circleci.
I can do this locally by specifying the spec files in the Cypress.json file, but I don't want to run these locally as it prevents me from using my computer while tests are running.
I can specify which files to run on circleci by listing them in the config.yml.
However, the problem with this approach is that I have to push a PR to github every time I want to run a different set of spec files (with no intention of merging this change to the repo).

I found this discussion on circle's forum that has a potential solution:
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/efficiently-testing-configuration-file-migrating-to-2-0/11620

I tried to implement it, but the build fails on circleci because it keeps reading my config.yml file incorrectly.

For example,

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
executors:
  latest-chrome:
    docker:
      - image: "cypress/browsers:node14.7.0-chrome84"
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          executor: latest-chrome
          browser: chrome
          spec: 
            "cypress/integration/test_lab.js,\
            cypress/integration/example/example.js"
```

is converted to this on circleci:

```
version: 2.1
orbs: {cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1}
executors:
  latest-chrome:
    docker:
    - {image: 'cypress/browsers:node14.7.0-chrome84'}
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
    - build: {}
```

Note that the config.yml builds correctly when I push it to github - just not when I am using the method mentioned in the link I provided above.

Comment: "the problem with this approach is that I have to push a PR to github every time I want to run a different set of spec files",  Have you tried Using a matrix to solve such a problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. Is that a circleci feature?

Comment: Update: 
I looked that up - it's a circleci feature. Using a matrix wouldn't solve my problem. I'm looking for a convenient way to pick and choose which test files to run. Ideally, I can do this using the circleci web app directly, but I can't find a way. 

For now, I'll just have to stick with pushing a PR, then closing that PR without merging once I'm done.